# Running NestJS in PM2 cluster mode when building a deployment with Yarn PNP

Tags: gitlab, nestjs, yarnpkg, pm2

#### Migrated from npm to yarn pnp

A few months ago we started to use yarn2 (pnpify) for our monorepo since the node_modules did grow to 200K packages. Thanks to yarn2 we reduced the build & deployment time for all packages from 40 minutes to 4-5 minutes which is really great.

Front-end packages are easily tree-shaked and bundled in order to create a small artifact and uploaded to a storage container.
Backend packages (Nestjs Rest & GraphQl API's) are a little bit tricky in order to run the builds with pm2 in a cluster mode.

#### PM2

With PM2 you can run your app in `fork` or in `cluster` mode.
When running your app on the same port, you need to use `cluster` mode.
`Fork` mode keeps saying port already in use after starting the first fork (which is totally legit)

Since we're using yarn2 we can only run our app using yarn as interpreter by running it as:

```
yarn node ./build/main.js
```

in order to have proper module resolution because node does not understand it.

**And here comes the issue:**
yarn (and npm) are not playing well in cluster mode.
This is because you need to use node itself as interpreter and not yarn (or npm)
So we ended up with the following ecosystem.config.js

```
{
    "apps": [
        {
            "args": "node ./build/main.js",
            "exec_mode": "cluster",
            "instances": "max",
            "interpreter": "bash",
            "name": "api",
            "script": "yarn",
            "time": true
        }
    ]
}
```

We shipped our deployment to a VM with more than 1 CPU core and reloaded the pm2 service with the new ecosystem. Everything was and stayed green but we noticed that only 1 process was actually listening to port 3000 and all other processes did throw an `EADDRINUSE` error.
yarn emits the error, instead of throwing it, so PM2 thinks the application is still alive.
Or at least, this was our conclusion...

Bundling NestJS is a no-go see: [bundled-nest](https://github.com/ZenSoftware/bundled-nest)

The only solution I have is to clusterize nestjs itself by doing something like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { fork, isMaster, on } from 'cluster';
import * as os from 'os';

const numCPUs = os.cpus().length;
// const randomNumber = (min: number, max: number) =>
//   Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;

@Injectable()
export class ClusterService {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-types
  static clusterize(callback: Function): void {
    if (isMaster) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-plusplus
      for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        fork();
      }

      on('exit', (worker, code) => {
        fork();
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log(
          `[Cluster] worker[${worker.process.pid}] died with status: [${code}], creating new worker`,
        );
      });
    } else {
      callback();
    }
  }
}
```

and run PM2 on a single instance, but this feels a little bit quirky since PM2 can do this for you... in a better way.

Is there a way to "eject" the node_modules with yarn2 so we could run the app as a real node process?
Is there a way to run PM2 in cluster mode on the same port while using yarn as interpreter?
How to throw an error in yarn2 instead of emitting it so PM2 will create a new process?

... or is there another solution to use just npm in gitlab and not have to wait 40 minutes to build the packages and run the nestjs app with the node interpreter n pm2?

Comment: Fixed the issue:
**package.json**
in the package.json add `"pm2:start": "yarn pm2 start ecosystem.config.js"`
**ecosystem.config.js** 
remove `interpreter` and `args` and just add the javascipt file to execute in `script`.
so now you can just run `yarn:pm2start`

Comment: ... `yarn pm2:start`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You don't need yarn to run application with yarn's module resolution.
The only thing you need is to require the `.pnp.js` when running the application with node as interpreter.
add `"interpreter_args": "--require /path/to/.pnp.js",` to your pm2 config

ecosystem.config.js:

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "my-app",
      "script": "./main.js",
      "interpreter_args": "--require /path/to/.pnp.js",
      "exec_mode": "cluster"
     }
  ]
}
```

Now you are able to execute `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js` without facing any errors regarding node modules not found.

Answer (score 0):

`yarn exec pm2 start ecosystem.config.js` and don't save the pm2 process.
pm2 is only able to resurrect in npm mode and will not execute your script in yarn mode.

downside is that you can't use the pm2 startup to survive a reboot from pm2. So you need to implement a systemd service by yourself which will execute a `yarn pm2:start` on startup

2 possible feature solutions:

- yarn2 will be able to eject the .yarn cache after build step to recreate node_modules in order to start your app in npm.
- pm2 will add a feature to start your app in yarn instead of npm in combination with cluster mode